# Django: reverse in ModelAdmin.Media.js

Tags: python, django, django-urls

This is the configuration of my urls. The main urls.py of the project is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^plugins/', include('plugins.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/',   include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

From here I include the following plugin urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^jsconfig/', 'plugins.views.js_config', name='plugins_js_config'),
)
```

The problem is in the Plugin ModelAdmin where I try to dynamically include the url to a view that returns a `text/javascript` page

```
class PluginConfigurationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (reverse('plugins_js_config'),)

admin.site.register(PluginConfiguration, PluginConfigurationAdmin)
```

As soon as I try to load any admin page, I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': u'plugins'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/(?P<app_label>auth)/$']
```

But if I hard-code the resolved url, it works as expected:

```
class Media:
    js = ('/plugins/jsconfig/',)
```

Why can't I get the reverse working in the admin.py page? Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use reverse_lazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`reverse_lazy()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead of the plain `reverse()`.  At the time of defining the `ModelAdmin` URLConf is not loaded yet.